# Recuperando valor combobox javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Estou com a seguinte situação:

Preciso saber uma forma de fazer com que o valor de uma opção do combobox seja o assunto de um e-mail que é enviado a partir do site.

Ex: Tenho dois combobox separados área e setor, ao selecionar essa duas opções preciso que o assunto do e-mail seja a opção que foi selecionada: `área > setor`

Comment: você já tem alguma coisa de código feito ? se tiver poste

Comment: Não precisa de JavaScript pra isso. HTML e PHP puro dão conta.

Comment: Thiago, [edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/88484/edit) sua pergunta e coloque o que você já fez.

Answer (score 0):

Usando apenas JavaScript:

**HTML**

```
<select id="area" name="area">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option value="Informática">Informática</option>
    <option value="RH">RH</option>
</select>

<select id="setor" name="setor">
</select>
```

**JavaScript (Utilizei o Jquery para facilitar):**

```
$(function(){
    var setores = {
        "Informática": ["Sistemas", "Suporte", "Redes"],
        "RH": ["Folha de pagamento", "Benefícios", "Contratações"]
    };

    $("#area").on('change', function(){
        var options = $("#setor");
        options.find('option').remove();

        if($(this).val() == "") return;

        $.each(setores[$(this).val()], function() {
            options.append
                ($("<option />").val(this).text(this)
                );
        });
    });
});
```

Exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0h9vgsx3/)

No php apenas pegue os valores dos dois `select` e concatene.

```
$_POST['area'].' > '.$_POST['setor']
```

Os valores dos `select` pode ser feito via ajax também